# Author-time vs run-time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, runtime

What is the difference between author-time and run-time in JavaScript? I am reading the YDKJS series and the author keeps mentioning author-time and it sounds like to me that author time is when the code is being written but I was hoping someone could clarify it a little more for me.

Context: *this* is not an author-time binding but a runtime binding. (From YDKJ *this* & Object Prototypes)

Comment: Some context of how the terms are used would help

Answer (score 10):

Author-time means - it's decided when you write the code (and compile it)... This is basically target our lexical scope 
Run-time means it's decided during execution. This basically target to Dynamic scope .

Answer (score 3):

Author-time can be taken to mean perception of program as you see it before compilation, which does not foresee variables values within run-time as in from user input. Within context of software meant for developers, *this* may be compounded in meaning at added levels of complexity. Having this or that called by someone coming from travels abroad and the loo- toilet-, will vary in uncertainty, but may possibly relate to their idea of loo from abroad to be taken for as difference in customs.

I read the next sections of book, and author time appears to not be wikipedia recognized scientific term while supposedly it's opposite of run-time, becomes more so a living thing subject to author's time "philosophical" manifestation which may include some unwittings 3rd party mention of *this* placing it in exotic conditions of which the 3rd party may not have had exact foreknowledge.

There're rules for how, finally, compiler interprets *this*, and while you may perceive what it will be taken to mean. It's utility comes from compiler calling *this* man commited crime in police station (this being runtime).